# How to update user profile picture in QuickBlox using php api?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter-3, quickblox

How to update user profile picture in Quickblox using php codeigntier ?

Documentation found at

http://quickblox.com/developers/Users

Answer (score 0):

after found rest api i have found the solution for how to upload profile picture to quickblox user.

there are three 3 steps for uploading content as per quickblox rest api
First you generate token from the quickblox and then perform these 3 steps

1. Create file

https://quickblox.com/developers/Content#Create_a_file

```
  $strFilename = '2.jpeg';
  $post_body = http_build_query(array(
        'blob[content_type]' => 'image/jpeg',
        'blob[name]' =>$strFilename,
    ));
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, QB_API_ENDPOINT.'blobs.json');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_body);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0',
        'QB-Token: ' . $token
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $error = curl_error($curl);


    if ($response) {
            return $response;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
    curl_close($curl);
```

After this curl call you have got the response and in response got the response like this

```
[blob] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7178102
        [uid] => f9cc9d7938c4468f8bdccdcb68fb5d8c00
        [content_type] => image/jpeg
        [name] => 2.jpeg
        [size] => 
        [created_at] => 2017-02-07T10:35:38Z
        [updated_at] => 2017-02-07T10:35:38Z
        [ref_count] => 1
        [blob_status] => 
        [set_completed_at] => 
        [public] => 1
        [last_read_access_ts] => 
        [lifetime] => 8600
        [account_id] => 56721
        [app_id] => 
        [blob_object_access] => Array
            (
                [id] => 7178102
                [blob_id] => 7178102
                [expires] => 2017-02-07T11:35:38Z
                [object_access_type] => Write
                [params] => https://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com/?Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&Expires=Tue%2C%2007%20Feb%202017%2011%3A35%3A38%20GMT&acl=public-read&key=f9cc9d7938c4468f8bdccdcb68fb5d8c00&policy=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%3D%3D&success_action_status=201&x-amz-algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&x-amz-credential=AKIAIY7KFM23XGXJ7R7A%2F20170207%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&x-amz-date=20170207T103538Z&x-amz-signature=5e236c3da60a922951c8ab6281ae82af3a88e37c15d8630ad6ff590610a87fd8
            )

    )
```

2. Upload file

so you have to used the params url parameters and make another call for uploading file

```
$strFilename = '2.jpeg';
    $url = 'https://qbprod.s3.amazonaws.com/';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'Content-Type' => $arr['Content-Type'],
        'Expires'=>$arr['Expires'],
        'acl'=>$arr['acl'],
        'key'=>$arr['key'],
        'policy'=>$arr['policy'],
        'success_action_status'=>$arr['success_action_status'],
        'x-amz-algorithm'=>$arr['x-amz-algorithm'],
        'x-amz-credential'=>$arr['x-amz-credential'],
        'x-amz-date'=>$arr['x-amz-date'],
        'x-amz-signature'=>$arr['x-amz-signature'],
        'file' => new CurlFile('2.jpeg', $arr['Content-Type'], $strFilename)
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 204) {
        echo 'Success!';
    } else {
        $error = substr($response, strpos($response, '<Code>') + 6);
        echo substr($error, 0, strpos($error, '</Code>'));
    }
    return $response;
```

so by using this code your content file will be uploaded and you got the location of the file and used as profile picture or etc .

3. Declare file

   ```
   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.quickblox.com/blobs/" . $strId . "/complete.xml");  // strId is blod id return by 1 step
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "blob[size]=10000"); //your file size
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");


    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Quickblox-Rest-Api-Version: 0.1.0";
     $headers[] = "Qb-Token: " . $token;
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
     curl_close($ch);
     return $result;
   ```

Please let me know the any issue regards the same.
Thanks